# Installing a Google Drive App as a local "unpacked" Chrome extension

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to write a Google Drive App, following instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/listing

I have created a Chrome extension (with a manifest.json and some icon images). My manifest.json has the following attributes set:

```
  "container" : "GOOGLE_DRIVE",
  "api_console_project_id" : "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
```

where all the X's are the twelve-digit ID I get from http://code.google.com/apis/console.

I install my extension using the "Load Unpacked Extension" button on the build-in Chrome extensions page for my browser (chrome://chrome/extensions).

But I can't get the app to show up in any of the drop-down menus in Google Drive. Do all Google-Drive-enabled apps have to be installed from the Chrome Web Store, or should I be able to install one from local files as described above?

Answer (score 5):

The app must be installed from the Chrome Web Store but you can publish it to test accounts only: https://developers.google.com/drive/listing#publish_to_test_accounts

Comment: This nugget of information is conspicuously missing from the integration docs. I'll also add that the open url domain must match exactly to one you have verified in google webmaster.